# How to create a nano precision table in tdengine

Tags: tdengine

I know that tdengine has supported nanosecond,microsecond and millisecond. But I do not know how to configure that while I tried to create a nano table yesterday.I think the there isn’t any special appreciate persition to put precision statement among a create sql statement.just like :

```
create table if not exists tableName (ts timestamp,col int,...)
```

I just want know how to configure a table’ precision in tdengine.can someone help ?

Answer (score 0):

you can create a database with nano precision, then all the tables under this database will be using nano precision.

```
create database test precision 'ns';
```